# Appended new divs, but they're not draggable?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag

I'm a newbie and have some problems with making new divs draggable.

The example is: http://jsbin.com/iyexi3/

The problem is when I show the dialog for the name, I create some divs, but they aren't draggable.

Answer (score 0):

You've made some elements that are hardcoded in the HTML draggable by doing this:

$('.seleccionable').draggable({
  drag: function(e, ui) {
                     $('#status_nombre').html($(this).attr('id'));
                $('#status_top').attr('value',$(this).css('top'));
                $('#status_left').attr('value',$(this).css('left'));
              }
  ,containment: '#layout'
  ,refreshPositions: true
  ,snap: true
  });

When you add a new element you need to call .draggable() for that one too.

One way to do it would be to put that selector/draggable code into a function and call it after you've added a new element.

Comment: im adding the line .draggable();

  $('#nv_objeto').click(function(){  
    var nbr =prompt("Please write the Object name...:","");
    $("#layout").append("<div id='"+c_nbr(nbr)+"' class='seleccionable' style='top: 300px; left: 400px; width : 40px; height : 40px; background-color : black;  position :absolute;'></div>").draggable();

and don't works

Comment: The append call is not returning the div that you want to make draggable, so it won't work. 

What I would suggest is putting the $('.seleccionable').draggable code you already have into a function and then call it after your .append call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you append a new element to the DOM, it doesn't inherit the event handlers of the existing draggable elements.

You may have some luck with [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

This will allow you to create live events on all current and future elements matching a selector. It's similar to the built-in live() method. I haven't used it but it should work with draggable.

Answer (score 0):

finally find the solution is afther append the new div...

```
$('#nv_objeto').click(function(){   
    var nbr =prompt("Por favor escriba el nombre del Objeto:","");
    $("#layout").append("<div id='"+c_nbr(nbr)+"' class='seleccionable' style='top: 300px; left: 400px; width : 40px; height : 40px; background-color : black;  position :absolute;'></div>");
    $('#layout > div:last').blur().draggable({
                drag: function(e, ui) {
                    $('#status_nombre').html($(this).attr('id'));
                    $('#status_top').attr('value',$(this).css('top'));
                    $('#status_left').attr('value',$(this).css('left'));
        }
        ,containment: '#layout'
        ,refreshPositions: true
        ,snap: true
    });
});
```

thanks for the help.